# Change in scope does not appear in child scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive `pr-items` rendering instances of child-directives `pr-item` using a template and `ng-repeat`:

```
app.directive('prItems', function(){
    console.log('prItems');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items:'=',
        },
        template:'<pr-item ng-repeat="item in items"></pr-item>',
    ...
});
```

The child directive `pr-item` renders content using another template:

```
app.directive('prItem', function($compile){
    console.log('prItem');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-style="{\'border-style\':item.border_style, \'color\':item.color}" style="cursor:pointer;"><span ng-if="item.selected">* </span>{{item.name}} {{item.selected}}</div>',
   ...
});
```

This works fine so far.

On a click on the item, the parent directive gets notified using an event via `$emit`. When the parent element changes state of one of the items, this change does not show up in the respective item as demonstrated in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/acSGENT3BL1QvS8ErzZP?p=preview).

Now I am curious what I'm missing.

Comment: Plunk is an empty plunk

Comment: @JoeEnzminger: Hmmm, sorry, cannot reproduce this. I see my example, even in another browser.

Comment: My bad.  Working on Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [corrected Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pw4ldSXxpv3BUD5ncgTR?p=preview)

I've tried to note my changes (as opposed to your version)

```
app.directive('prItems', function(){
    console.log('prItems');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items:'=',
        },
        template:'<pr-item ng-repeat="item in items"></pr-item>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            console.log('prItems.link, scope.$id = ' + scope.$id);
            scope.$on('onSelecting', function (event, item) {
                console.log('prItems: onSelecting ' + item.name);
                //clear the selected flag for the other items
                angular.forEach(scope.items, function (value) {
                    if (value.selected) {
                        //console.log(value);
                        value.selected = false;
                    }
                });
                //set it for the item that was sent in
                item.selected = true;

                //change, no $scope.$apply - not needed here
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('prItem', function($compile){
    console.log('prItem');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //ng-style will change camel case to - case borderStyle works (instead of using 'border-style' with escaped quotes.
        template: '<div ng-style="{borderStyle:item.border_style, \'color\':item.color}" style="cursor:pointer;">CLICK ME: <span ng-if="item.selected">* </span>{{item.name}} {{item.selected}}</div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            console.log('prItem.controller, $scope.$id = ' + $scope.$id);
            //I left this in as-is, but there is a better way to do this by just using the template ($watch shouldn't be required)
            $scope.$watch('item.selected', function (val) {
                console.log('prItem.selected ' + $scope.item.name + ' changed to ' + val);
                $scope.item.border_style = val ? 'solid' : 'none';
                //console.log('$scope.item.border_style = ' + $scope.item.border_style);
            });
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            console.log('prItem.link ' + scope.item.name + ', scope.$id = ' + scope.$id);

              elem.on('mousedown touchdown', function () {
                //console.log('touché!');
                //scope.$apply should "wrap" non-angular code.  In the old version , you were calling scope.$apply() inline
                scope.$apply(function(){
                  scope.$emit('onSelecting', scope.item);
                  //instead of changing scope.selected, change item.selected - this change was probably not necessary
                  item.selected = !item.selected;
                });
                //old $scope.$apply();
              });
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT:  Without $watch

```
app.directive('prItem', function($compile){
    console.log('prItem');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //ng-style will change camel case to - case borderStyle works (instead of using 'border-style' with escaped quotes.
        template: '<div ng-style="{borderStyle:item.selected ? \'solid\' : \'none\', \'color\':item.color}" style="cursor:pointer;">CLICK ME: <span ng-if="item.selected">* </span>{{item.name}} {{item.selected}}</div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            console.log('prItem.controller, $scope.$id = ' + $scope.$id);
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            console.log('prItem.link ' + scope.item.name + ', scope.$id = ' + scope.$id);

              elem.on('mousedown touchdown', function () {
                //console.log('touché!');
                //scope.$apply should "wrap" non-angular code.  In the old version , you were calling scope.$apply() inline
                scope.$apply(function(){
                  scope.$emit('onSelecting', scope.item);
                  //instead of changing scope.selected, change item.selected - this change was probably not necessary
                  item.selected = !item.selected;
                });
                //old $scope.$apply();
              });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just show the delta, which is really that the OP has forgotten to actually set `item.selected` to `true`? And, come to think of it, wouldn't it would be more appropriate to be done as a comment and the question closed for "typo" reason?

Comment: @JoeEnzminger: Thanks to your answer, It turned out that the single real problem was the reference to `selected` instead of `item.selected` in the `$watch` and the toggle statement. The `$apply` also works in the direct call form. But I'll investigate on the form you proposed.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger Just uncovered your comment regarding the not necessary use of `$watch` that could be replaced by template magic. Would you mind giving me a hint?

Comment: Sure - updated the answer.  The change is in the template parameter.